# WPF: How to change the visibility of my ComboBox Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datatemplate

I know that this topic is already answered, but i couldn't solve the problem with the solution that i found. So here is my code:

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" Name="griglia" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Test}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="DataGridColumnHeader"  >
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Selezione}" SelectedValuePath="Selezionato" Width="100" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.Selezione}"  SelectionChanged="Test_SelectionChanged">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Oggetto}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

In few words, i have a custom datagrid which is bound to a datatable. The header of each column, is a combobox, whose source is an observable collection of this class:

```
public class PopolazioneCombo 
{
    public string Oggetto { get; set; }
    private bool selezionato = false;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    public bool Selezionato
    {
        get { return !selezionato; }
        set
        {
            if(selezionato != value)
            {
                selezionato = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selezionato");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the following: I need to switch the visibility of each selected item to collapsed in all the comboboxes (since they share the same source). I tried to create a custom SelectionChanged event in which i change the "Selezionato" value and i bound the visibility of the textblock like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Oggetto}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Selezionato, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The problem with this is that, not only it make my SelectedItem not visible in the combobox, but also the ComoBoxItem are not synchronized, so it's not working at all as intended.

EDIT: this is the collection

```
 public ObservableCollection<PopolazioneCombo> Selezione
    {
        get
        {
            return selezione;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selezione != value)
            {
                selezione = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Selezione");
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: My requirement is that, if in any of the N combobox an item is selected, then, that item cannot be selected by anyone, until he lose the SelectedItem status. For instance let's assume i have 2 combobox and a collection of 4 Item (x,y,a,b) . If x is selected in ComboBox1, then x can't be selected in none of the 2 ComboBox until the SelectedItem of the ComboBox1 change (from x to y for instance). Now i can even accept the fact that the item in the dropdown is just disabled if it makes the things easier, i just need the fact that it cannot be selected again if he is already selected

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't be changing the visibility of the items this way, you would be adding or removing them from the  collection property that `ItemsSource` is bound to on your viewmodel.  If all the bindings are referencing the same instance of your View Model, everything will stay in sync.

Comment: The first part is more or less what is happening. Of course i don't want this. My Collection must retain all the items. Only one property of an items should change, and that property should determine the visibility in the dropdown. The synchronization problem is something i cannot explain. When i choose an item from, let's say the first combobox, i can't see it in the following comboboxes, but i can still see it in the first. If i choose an element from the second combobox after that, i can't see it in the following combobxes, but i still can see it in the first and the second one etc..

Comment: You can use `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle` to set `Visibility` to `Collapsed` on certain items with a DataTrigger. The details may get ugly. Another option, probably better, is to populate the ComboBox with a filtered CollectionView

Comment: the combobox.ItemContainerStyle won't work in my situation, since there will be times, where the itemcontainer status is NotStarted. Could you provide an example for the CollectionView?

Comment: @DanieleSartori You would do that by adding a new property to the viewmodel that is a `CollectionView`, and bind to that. The `CollectionView` is attached to the "real" list of objects, and set to filter based on some property.  In the end, it would work similarly to my original suggestion, except that you would have both the filtered and unfiltered list available on the view model.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this can work. I'm still trying to find a way to do the binding, but from my first few try and from some reading around internet, i saw that the CollectionView have always the first item as selected by default. This would be a real problem for me since i have to keep the selected items null (and change only when they are actually setted) to grant all the process to work

Comment: I've never actually used it in this way, so I can't say for sure one way or the other, but that behavior would surprise me.  I'm still standing by my original solution, where the viewmodel has an `ObservableCollection` for each `ListBox` that contains only the items that actually belong in that `ListBox`.

Comment: CollectionViews can also be defined in XAML, with the filter in the codebehind.  *"the combobox.ItemContainerStyle won't work in my situation, since there will be times, where the itemcontainer status is NotStarted"* -- I have no idea what you're referring to there, but you're mistaken anyway.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i misreaded. I thought you were referring to the itemcontainergenerator.

Comment: The real problem here, is that the SelectedItem property of the combobox is related to the source of the combobox. If that particular item is removed from the source (either way cause i'm using a collection view or because i changed the visibility) then the Selecteditem will be null.

Comment: I just did a quick test and found that hiding the items via a trigger in ItemContainerStyle didn't prevent them from being selected. In fact, you can cycle through the list with the mousewheel and select one that isn't visible.

Comment: Is it your requirement that hidden item should *never* be selected? Or that it should be possible for a hidden item to be selected?

Comment: @EdPlunkett My requirement is that, if in any of the N combobox an item is selected, then, that item cannot be selected by anyone, until he lose the SelectedItem status.  For instance let's assume i have 2 combobox and a collection of 4 Item (x,y,a,b) . If x is selected in ComboBox1, then x can't be selected in none of the 2 ComboBox until the SelectedItem of the ComboBox1 change (from x to y for instance). Now i can even accept the fact that the item in the dropdown is just disabled if it makes the things easier, i just need the fact that it cannot be selected again if he is already selected

Comment: That's sensible but it's not straightforward to make it happen. I tried something with ItemContainerStyle and got 90% of the way there, but there were cases where it pushed "unselected" to the items when I didn't want it to. I do have a working version that uses the ComboBox.SelectionChanged event. Want that?

Comment: You should add that last statement of your requirement to the top of the question; it's much clearer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Any help would be appreciate, so if you want to share your version of ComboBox.SelectionChanged event it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements:

1. Multiple combo boxes all display the same set of options.
2. If an item is selected in a combo box, it may not be selected in any *other* combo box.

We'll do the hiding and disabling with triggers in an `ItemContainerStyle` on the comboboxes, driven by the `bool Selezionato` property of the combo box items. We'd prefer to set `Selezionato` with a `Binding` in the style as well, but I found that it was deselecting items at times when I didn't want it to, so I did it in a `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` handler instead.

```
<Style 
    x:Key="SingleSelectionComboBoxItem" 
    TargetType="ComboBoxItem" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}"
    >
    <!-- This unselects sometimes when you don't want it to. -->
    <!--
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selezionato, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selezionato}" Value="True">
            <!-- Hide it -->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <!-- Also prevent user from selecting it via arrows or mousewheel -->
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

ComboBoxes. I'm leaving out some of the properties you had. What matters for my addition to your code is `ItemContainerStyle` and `SelectionChanged`:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Selezione}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Oggetto"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SingleSelectionComboBoxItem}"
    SelectionChanged="SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged"
    />
```

Code behind:

```
private void SingleSelectionComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems.OfType<PopolazioneCombo>())
    {
        item.Selezionato = false;
    }

    foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.OfType<PopolazioneCombo>())
    {
        item.Selezionato = true;
    }
}
```

---

Another thing I noticed along the way:

You had the `PopolazioneCombo.Selezionato` getter returning `!selezionato` -- probably a typo, but if not, a bad idea!

```
public bool Selezionato
{
    get { return selezionato; }
    set
    {
        if (selezionato != value)
        {
            selezionato = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selezionato");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are almost there. The problem is (and it's a thing that i couldn't resolve in my previous try) that if you try to select something on a combox, this reflect on the following comboboxes, but not on the one which triggered the selection change. If you select an item on the next combo, the same thing happen, but the change doesn't reflect also on the previous and so on.

Comment: I'll describe an example to let the things be clearer:    Let's suppose that we have 3 comboboxes (C1,C2,C3) with 5 item (x,y,z,a,b). On C1 we select the item "x". Then the dropdown of C2 and C3 will be composed of [y,z,a,b] but the dropdown of C1 will show [x,y,z,a,b]. Now we select "y" from the item of C2. The dropdown of C3 will be [z,a,b], the dropdown of C2 will be [y,z,a,b], and the dropdown of C1 will be [x,y,z,a,b].

Comment: I found which is the problem. Every time you open the dropdown of a combobx, it's seems that something break, and the change you make, won't reflect in the combobx. The only thing i can thing is that, this problem is related to the ItemContainerGenerator.Status . If you don't open the dropdown, then the status will stay NotStarted and each change you make to the itemcontainers will be saved. At the moment that you open the dropdown, The Container will be Generated and the changes won't be shown

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I found the solution to the problem. You can check it here if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539768/wpf-how-to-recreate-itemcontainer/44540249#44540249

Comment: @DanieleSartori Does your combo box item PopolazioneCombo implement INotifyPropertyChanged? It has the event, but does it name the interface?

Comment: i'm a dumb. I totally forgot to add " : INotifyPropertyChanged" near the class name. Now your solution work as intended

Comment: @DanieleSartori I always use a common base class for viewmodels that implements the interface. Otherwise I'd do that twice a week.